# Playing mp3 with delphi

Tags: delphi, audio, mp3

Which component to use to play mp3 files from streams/files and also to know the lenght in seconds of that mp3 stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the components at [www.mitov.com](http://www.mitov.com) which has an Audio suite that can handle this type of file.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Bass audio library.

http://www.un4seen.com/

Search for "MP3" on the 3D Buzz site.  They have a series of video tutorials that walk you through the creation of your own MP3 player in Delphi using this library.  Free membership required.

http://www.3dbuzz.com

Answer (score 2):

try [DSPack](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=4) which are set of Components to write Multimedia Applications.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NewAc](http://symmetrica.net/newac/) components for audio conversion and filtering, it can play MP3 and several others formats.